# DateTime Input: Changes it's format once in production (Azure)

Tags: azure, date, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc

I've encountered this situation where, while working **on local**, my `input (type: datetime)` respects the format given: **dd/MM/yyyy**, but once it goes **online**, the input changes the expected date format to **MM/dd/yyyy.**

*The View:*

```
    <td>
        <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))">
            <div>
                <input data-fomat="0:dd/MM/yyyy" type="datetime" class="datepicker form-control" 
                  asp-for="@item.FechaDesignado" 
                  id="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","ownID",item.StoreID))" 
                  form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.FechaDesignado" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

*The Model:*

```
public class Store
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaDesignado { get; set; }
}
```

*The Controller:*

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Management")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Management(int? id)
    {
        var storetoupdate = _context.Stores.SingleOrDefault(m => m.StoreID == id.Value);
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
            storetoupdate, "item",
            s => s.StoreName, s => s.IncomePeriodicity, s=>s.Usuario, s => s.FechaDesignado))
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Management");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Management");
    }
```

**Results:**

When the project is tested on local, I can enter the following date:

[image]

And the value updates just fine, **but** if I test it online it only will save the value if I sent it this format MM/dd/yyy but it will present it on dd/MM/yyyy:

[image]

I don't see the reason for this to change once is online but I'm trying to find the way for this to work properly. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Because the culture on the server expects dates in `MM/dd/yyyy` format (change the culture in your `web.config` file)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, Stephen. Applying this change to my Startup.cs did the job.